# Verilog parallel to serial transmitter module outputs 0

Tags: verilog

I use Modelsim to run Verilog code for parallel to serial transmitter, it complied successfully but the simulation gives wave for only `data_in` and all other signals with no waves and their values are `St0`, `St1` and `HiZ`.

`Serial_out` wave should appear as consecutive bits not constant line as shown here:
[image]

Module

```
module parallel_to_serial_transmitter #(
  parameter DATA_WIDTH = 32,  // Data width (e.g., 32 for 32-bit data)
  parameter BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 // Buffer size in bits
) (
  input clk,
  input rst,
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_in,
  output reg serial_out,
  output reg fifo_read,
  output  fifo_full,
  output  fifo_empty,
  output reg pts_write,
  output reg pts_shift,
  output reg mux_sel
);

  // Signals
  reg [BUFFER_SIZE-1:0] fifo_buffer; // Buffer for storing data
  reg [9:0] rd_ptr, wr_ptr;        // Read and write pointers for FIFO
  reg [2:0] state;                  // State machine state
  reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] shift_reg;    // Shift register for serial data
  reg [4:0] shift_count;            // Counter for data bits
  reg [3:0] zero_count;             // Counter for consecutive zeros

  // State machine states
  localparam IDLE = 0;
  localparam DATA_LOAD = 1;
  localparam LEADING_ONE = 2;
  localparam DATA_SHIFT = 3;
  localparam STAFF_ONE = 4;

  // State transitions and actions
  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (rst) begin
      state <= IDLE;
      fifo_read <= 1'b0;
      pts_write <= 1'b0;
      pts_shift <= 1'b0;
      mux_sel <= 1'b0;
      shift_reg <= 1'b0;
      shift_count <= 5'b00000;
      zero_count <= 4'b0000;
      rd_ptr <= 10'b0000000000;
      wr_ptr <= 10'b0000000000;
      fifo_buffer <= 1024'b0;
    end else begin
      case (state)
        IDLE: begin
          fifo_read <= ~fifo_full; // Read if FIFO not full
          if (~fifo_full) begin
            fifo_buffer[wr_ptr] <= data_in;
            wr_ptr <= wr_ptr + 1;
            state <= DATA_LOAD;
          end
          serial_out <= 1'b0; // Transmit zero in idle state
        end
        DATA_LOAD: begin
          if (rd_ptr != wr_ptr) begin
            shift_reg <= fifo_buffer[rd_ptr];
            rd_ptr <= rd_ptr + 1;
            zero_count <= 4'b0000;
            state <= LEADING_ONE;
          end
        end
        LEADING_ONE: begin
          serial_out <= 1'b1; // Transmit leading one
          pts_write <= 1'b1;
          shift_count <= 5'b00000;
          state <= DATA_SHIFT;
        end
        DATA_SHIFT: begin
          pts_shift <= 1'b1;
          serial_out <= shift_reg[0];
          shift_reg <= shift_reg >> 1;
          shift_count <= shift_count + 1;
          zero_count <= (shift_reg[0] == 1'b0) ? zero_count + 1 : 4'b0000;
          if (shift_count == DATA_WIDTH - 1) begin
            if (zero_count == 6) begin
              state <= STAFF_ONE;
            end else begin
              state <= DATA_LOAD;
            end
          end
        end
        STAFF_ONE: begin
          serial_out <= 1'b1; // Transmit staff one
          pts_write <= 1'b1;
          zero_count <= 4'b0000;
          state <= DATA_LOAD;
        end
      endcase
    end
  end

  // FIFO logic (replace with your actual FIFO implementation)
  //reg fifo_full, fifo_empty;
  assign fifo_full = (wr_ptr - rd_ptr == BUFFER_SIZE -1);
  assign fifo_empty = (wr_ptr == rd_ptr);

   
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module parallel_to_serial_transmitter_tb;

  // Parameters
  localparam DATA_WIDTH = 32;
  localparam BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
  
  // Signals
  reg clk;
  reg rst;
  reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_in;
  wire serial_out;
  wire fifo_read;
  wire fifo_full;
  wire fifo_empty;
  wire pts_write;
  wire pts_shift;
  wire mux_sel;
  
  // Instantiate the module under test
  parallel_to_serial_transmitter #(
    .DATA_WIDTH(DATA_WIDTH),
    .BUFFER_SIZE(BUFFER_SIZE)
  ) dut (
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .data_in(data_in),
    .serial_out(serial_out),
    .fifo_read(fifo_read),
    .fifo_full(fifo_full),
    .fifo_empty(fifo_empty),
    .pts_write(pts_write),
    .pts_shift(pts_shift),
    .mux_sel(mux_sel)
  );

  // Clock generation
  always #5 clk = ~clk;
  
  // Initial stimulus
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    rst = 1;
    data_in = 0;
    
    // Reset
    #10;
    rst = 0;
    
    // Stimulus
    #20;
    data_in = 32'h12345678;
    #100;
    data_in = 32'h87654321;
    #100;
    data_in = 32'hABCDEF01;
    #100;
    
     
 // Add more stimulus as needed...
    //initial begin 
   //$display( clk,rst,data_in,serial_out,fifo_read,fifo_full,fifo_empty,pts_write,pts_shift,mux_sel);
   //end 
    // Finish simulation
    #100;
    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

I write the code for parallel to serial transmitter and the test bench and expecting waves for the signal which didn't appear

**Edit:** This question is not a duplicate at all and it has no connection to the linked duplicate question. Although, there are a couple of issues that exist in the Verilog code but that what makes this a legit question.

Comment: Your signal list shows both `fifo_full` and `fifo_ful`.  You have a typo in your testbench.

Comment: I believe that there is no connection between this question and the duplicate question linked with it. This is a mistake.